# How do I improve performance of JointJS with many links?

Tags: jointjs

After profiling the code it looks like bbox function is being called repeatedly. I cannot remove marker-source, marker-target and connection-wrap because I need those features. Is there a way to improve performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `marker-source` and `marker-target` with [SVG Markers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker). It's relatively easy to implement if your application does not require different sizes and colors of markers. For instance:

1. Define you own marker arrow.

```js
var arrowMarker = V('marker', {
   viewBox: "0 0 10 10",
   refX: 9,
   refY: 5,
   markerWidth: 6,
   markerHeight: 6,
   orient: "auto"
}, [
   V('path', {
       'd': "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z",
       'fill': 'green'
   })
]);
```

2. Add the marker to paper's [SVG Defs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs) so it can be reused later for multiple times.

```js
V(paper.defs).append(arrowMarker);
```

3. Finally put the marker on a link. Use the [`marker-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-end) or [`marker-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-start) property to define the `target` resp. `source` marker.

```js
var link = new joint.dia.Link({
    markup: '<path class="connection"/><path class="connection-wrap"/>',
    attrs: {
        '.connection': {
            'stroke': 'green',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'marker-end': 'url(#' + arrowMarker.attr('id') + ')'
        }
    }
});
```

There is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kumilingus/fjzvqhhk/) with an example and other useful performance tips.